# Regular grid of points in arbitrary dimensions

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

Is there an efficient way to output a collection of equally spaced points in Mathematica, in arbitrary dimensions?

In 1D there is the `Range` function, which given two endpoints and a spacing, outputs the numbers between those endpoints, spaced by that spacing, starting from the smallest endpoint. I'm wondering whether this can be generalized to multiple dimensions efficiently, for example, if one would like to produce a grid of equally spaced points in the square $[0,1]^2$ with spacing $1/2$, the output should be `{{0,0},{0,1/2},{0,1},{1/2,0},{1/2,1/2},{1/2,1},{1,0},{1,1/2},{1,1}}`.

Comment: `Tuples[Range[smallest,largest,spacing],dimensions]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 0, 1, 1/2}, {j, 0, 1, 1/2}, {k, 0, 1, 1/2}]
Array[List, {3, 3, 3}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
Outer[List, Range[0, 1, 1/2], Range[0, 1, 1/2], Range[0, 1, 1/2]]
Tuples[{Range[0, 1, 1/2], Range[0, 1, 1/2], Range[0, 1, 1/2]}]
Tuples[Range[0, 1, 1/2], 3]
```

I extended to three dimensions to highlight the patterns. Also, the title mentioned "regular grid", so I included examples that don't produce the "flat" output.

Table looks to be the most difficult to extend/modify, but it's the most explicit. The second version of Tuples is the easiest to extend, but requires that all dimensions have the same scale. Note also that Tuples produces the "flat" output requested. Outer and the first Tuples are a nice balance of flexibility and simplicity.

**Edit**

The above was accepted as the answer, but I feel compelled to note that Syed's solution is really the most semantically aligned with the way the problem was posed. Even though it's been around awhile, I wasn't aware of CoordinateBoundsArray, and it will definitely come in handy for me. I'll record Syed's suggestion here so it gets attention as the accepted answer.

```
CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 1/2]
```

(You can, of course, flatten the result.)

Answer (score 6):

You could also explore the many variations of `CoordinateBoundsArray` from the docs. For your particular example:

```
Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 1/2], 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}, {1,
>    1/2}, {1, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Nice! Learned a new one!

Comment: I wish there were some sort of community approved answer, because I'd definitely vote for your solution.

Comment: @lericr The structure of Mathematica is such that you can have  multiple valid answers to a question. Building things from the ground up is satisfying but a built-in solution can be utilized to reduce maintenance costs. Here I note that all solutions in Mathematica are not created equal in terms of memory/speed/update frequency etc. Thanks for your kind words and for appending this solution to your answer.